# Switching Micro SDs

Tags: sd-card

Is it possible if I load one micro SD card with OSMC and the other with Raspbian and then switch them depending on which software I want to use at the moment? Will this not work or cause damage to the Raspberry Pi 2 B?

Comment: Trust me when I tell you that I do it all the time! Particularly between those two operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! I now use two micro SD cards and switch them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you do a clean shutdown on one OS before switching out the SD cards, you should be fine. It's how the Raspberry Pi was designed to be used.

Answer (score 5):

That would work fine, as long as you shutdown the Pi. If your SD is 16GB+, you can cram 2/3 OSes onto it using NOOBS. When you start it up, it gives a menu asking which one.